# Connecting to WebSocket server via .net.Socket java\android

Tags: java, android, sockets, websocket, java-websocket

I have a WebSocket server on azure `ws://myServer.azurewebsites.net:80`

I am able to connect to it `var ws = new WebSocket('ws://feet.azurewebsites.net:80');`
and then send some message and get it back.

I'm trying now to build an app on android and to connect to this WebSocket.

I don't want to use this websocket from git

`import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;`

`import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;`

I would like to use the `java.net.Socket`

I'm trying to start a new socket and I get a `UnknownHostException`. I'm just trying to get the ip this way: `InetAddress.getByName("ws://myServer.azurewebsites.net:80");` and i get the `UnknownHostException`.

I also tried to create a socket:

`Socket socket  = new Socket("ws://myServer.azurewebsites.net", 80);`
 and again get the `UnknownHostException`

Is there a way to use `net.Socket`? What am I doin wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: "ws://myServer.azurewebsites.net:80" is not a hostname; it's a combination of protocol, hostname and port.

Comment: So do u have any solution how to do it?

Comment: I think you should be able to arrive to a solution by yourself using the information that I posted above.

Comment: ok, i managed. Thanks